# setting values if they don't already exist

Tags: php

What's the best way for setting values if they don't already exist in PHP?

Is it safe to use

```
$color = $option['color'] ?: 'blue';
```

Instead of

```
$color = isset($option['color']) ? $option['color'] : 'blue';
```

Or there's a much better way?

Comment: Note the those are not the same!

Comment: Please avoid opinionated question for "best way to do X". Rather state what you are looking for in the solution. Ist it "most concise" or "less error-prone"?

Comment: It is called "The null coalescing operator"

Comment: `$color = $option['color'] || 'blue'` wont be the same for this specific example?

Answer (score 10):

In PHP 7 you can now use the [Null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/de/migration70.new-features.php):

```
$color = $option['color'] ?? 'blue';
```

This is the same as this in PHP5:

```
$color = isset($option['color']) ? $option['color'] : "blue";
```

Comment: I already know about this approach but I'm still looking for a safe way that works with versions < PHP7.

Comment: Would it not be the same as  `$color = $option['color'] ? $option['color'] : "blue";`? The main difference is when the first argument is a function,

Comment: @Martijn with $color = $option['color'] ? $option['color'] : "blue"; you are testing if the variable contains a truthy value, while isset checks if the variable has been set.

Comment: @TaimurAziz Then the safest way would be to use $color = isset($option['color']) ? $option['color'] : "blue";

Answer (score 1):

Both are the same, but `$color = isset($option['color']) ? $option['color'] : 'blue';` prevents a PHP Warning exception